# Show/convert only alphanumeric data in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, birt

I'm a bit new to sql, and I'm using birt report designer.

One column of mine has a result of

```
Name
John
Blake
Anna12345
Jose
Mika
Camille3214
Owen
Cynthia12222
```

I would like this column to only show those alphanumeric data, example:

```
Name
Anna12345
Camille3214
Cynthia12222
```

Do I have to convert this or change the data type? If I change the data type there is no varchar or nvarchar in the options.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$'`

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally we like to see that you've had a go at your problem before asking us for help - so usually we'd like you to put an example of code you've tried (even if it is not working) into your question. That shows that you're willing to go to some effort yourself, and also lets us better see what you're trying to do, so we can help you more.